# Cannot mount Ext4/LUKS anymore

Tags: disk, ext4, luks

My ubuntu hangs after some hours, regularly, but after last reboot I cannot mount my Ext4 partition that sits on top of LUKS.

[image]

Also dmesg lookup:

[image]

Comment: @KazWolfe Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this problem happened because your EXT4 partition's journal has appeared to become corrupt. Fortunately, this is relatively easy to fix.

1. **Decrypt Your Device**
   In order to run `fsck` on your encrypted EXT4 filesystem, we need to decrypt the device first. Run the below command, replacing `/dev/sdXY` with the LUKS partition we're targeting:

   ```
   sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 luks_USB
   ```
2. **Repair Your Device**
   If `fsck` wants to play nice, you can just run it on the now-exposed dm device. Replace `dm-1` with whatever the DM is actually reported as, and do whatever FSCK wants you to do:

   ```
   sudo fsck /dev/dm-1
   ```

`fsck` might refuse to work on your drive, citing that it's "mounted." If this is the case, we need to do some trickery to fix the broken things. If this is the case, do step 1 above and then:

1. **Image Your Drive**
   Once you have your drive mounted, we're going to have to image it. You can place the image somewhere useful, like in your home folder. Run the below command paying very careful attention to not mix up the `if` and `of` statements. Replace `dm-1` with whatever your drive's DM is, as per the norm:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/dm-1 of=~/drive.img
   ```
2. **Repair The Image**
   Now, we can run `fsck` on the image itself. Be sure to (as always) listen to `fsck` and do whatever it wants you to do to fix the device.

   ```
   sudo e2fsck ~/drive.img
   ```
3. **Restore The Drive**
   Once we have a working image (you can test with `mount`), we can write it back to the USB device with the below command. Be very careful that you're specifying the right targets for `dd`, or else you will lose data:

   ```
    sudo dd if=~/drive.img of=/dev/dm-1
   ```

Once your drive is fixed (with either path), run luksClose on your device, and go back to your normal life with a working encrypted drive.